# Relationship between inverse of related matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Suppose I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $m \geq n$ and suppose that a matrix $G=(A^T A)^{-1}$ exists.

Now suppose that I have an other matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ that is a **diagonal matrix** and whose entries on the diagonal can only be 0 or 1

Define $C=BA$ and $H=(C^T C)^{-1}$

Is there some particular relationship between $G$ and $H$?

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but here are some ideas.

So matrix multiplication is easily remembered as row times column. So when we calculate $A^TA$, we are actually calculating column times column. So you can think of the matrix $A^TA$ as containing all the inner products between the columns of $A$.

Now, the matrix $B$ has easy properties: $B^2=B$ and $B^T=B$. Hence $C^TC=A^TB^TBA=A^TBA$. Lets calculate the $i,j$-th element of $C^TC$. We find that $$(A^TBA)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^m A_{ki}B_{kk}A_{kj}.$$
Hence the $i,j$-th entry of $C^TC$ contains the inner product between the $i$-th column of $A$ and the $j$-th column of $A$, but we delete the $k$-th components of the columns when $B_{kk}=0$.

In fact this calculation shows that the matrix $C^TC$ is independent of the rows of $A$ corresponding to the (diagonal) zeroes in $B$. Thus the matrix $H$ is independent of the rows of $A$ corresponding to zeroes in $B$. But clearly, the matrix $G$ does depend on this. To me, this seems to suggest that there is no nice relation between $G$ and $H$.

Comment: Thank you for your contribute.

Comment: Where did you find this question?

Comment: I am currently working in the field of applied statistic.
I have a linear system $y=Hx+\epsilon$ where $y$ is a vector (mx1) of observed random variables, and i have to estimate a state vector $x$ (nx1) ($H$ is an mxn matrix $\epsilon$ is nx1 vector).
There is a linear relationship between $x$ and $y$ through the matrix $H$.
Also, in this mathematical model a gaussian random vector $\epsilon$ is present (iid components).
The best way (in a statistical minimum mean square error) to estimate $x$ is:
$\hat{x}=(H^TH)^{-1}H^T y$

Comment: without going into the derivation the estimation vector is corrupted by a gaussian random vector whose covariance matrix is $(H^TH)^{-1}$
For my work i have to consider the situation where one or more of  the measurements are neglected.
This corresponds to a new system $y_R=H_r x+\epsilon_R$.
In this case the covariance matrix of the estim. error is $({H_R}^TH_R)^{-1}$
I also noticed that this can be expressed as $(H^T B^T B H)^{-1}$
where B is my diagonal matrix with zeros in the position of the neglected measurements.
It is important for this work to evaluate the relationship between

Comment: the two covariance matrices and i was wondering if it was possible to derive a simple, closed formula relationship.
In the system $y_R=H_r x+\epsilon_R$ $y_R$ is an m-1 x1 vector $H_r$ is the matrix $H$ with a given row deleted (it is thus an m-1x n matrix) ,$x$ is an nx1 vector and $\epsilon_R$ is an m-1 vector.
I do not know if my brief explanation was clear, in any case thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, it is pretty clear. I'm quite sure that there is not going to be a closed formula, unfortunately.